# Calling a method on an object

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to write a roulett simulator. I am trying to simulate the real world where you have a wheel and a croupier and the croupier spins the wheel. In Object Oriented Programming that means calling a method on another object from a differnt object. Is the code below where I pass the wheel obect around the correct way in C# to do this?

Thanks in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wheel luckyWheel = new Wheel();
            Croupier niceLady = new Croupier();
            niceLady.SpinWheel(luckyWheel);
        }
    }

    class Wheel
    {

        public void Spin()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wheel Spun");
        }
    }

    class Croupier
    {
        public void SpinWheel(Wheel spinMe)
        {
            spinMe.Spin();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you got?

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for such questions.

Comment: Off topic, belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is more of a code review question. Consider posting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct and also good way to do the stuff, as your code becomes a testable.
As you have *functionality* in one class `Wheel` , *executors* of that functionality in others: `Croupier` , ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct for a start. I advise you separating the classes into different .cs files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the right way to do that, as your both classes are in the same assembly you can declare the method `Spin()` internal.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it would be to pass the wheel to the courier when you create that class. The constructor would then store the wheel reference in a field, and then when you spin the wheel, the croupier can access the wheel via the local field.

Like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wheel wheel = new Wheel();
        Croupier croupier = new Croupier(wheel);
        croupier.SpinWheel();
    }
}

class Wheel
{
    public void Spin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wheel Spun");
    }
}

class Croupier
{
    private Wheel wheel;

    public Croupier(Wheel wheel)
    {
        this.wheel = wheel;
    }

    public void SpinWheel()
    {
        wheel.Spin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can improve it as Adam K Dean stated which leads you to use the strategy pattern as explain by the dotFactory [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx).